# How can I start with this problem and fix my code?

Tags: c

The question: write a program that gets a list of numbers ( lets say 4 numbers ) and an extra number and checks if the extra number equals to the multiplying of two numbers from the list.  If yes return true else return false.
For example a number list is ( 2,4,8,16) an extra number is 32, the program checks if 32 is equal to two numbers of the numbers from the list, and return true, in this example it will, because 32 equals to, my solution is below but its not correct, any help appreciated

```c
int i;
int b;
int listA[4] = {2, 4, 8, 10};
printf("Enter your Extra number value \n");
scanf("%d", &b);
for(i=0; i<4; i++){//?
if(listA[i] * listA[i+] == b){// i+1 ?
    printf("True! \n");
}else{
    printf("False \n");
}
```

Comment: @Majd Use two enclosed loops.

Comment: ...as in `for(int i=0; i<4; i++) { for(int j=i+1; j<4; j++) { if(listA[i] * listA[j] == b) {...}}}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To start with approach these sort of problems in the easiest possible method. using nested for loop.

As mentioned in one of the comments add a nested for loop.

```
int i=0;
int j=0;
int b=0;
int listA[4] = {2, 4 , 8 , 10};
printf("Enter your Extra number value \n");
scanf("%d" ,&b);
for(i=0; i<4  ; i++){//?
    for (j=i; j<4; j++) {
        if(listA[i] * listA[j] == b)
        {
            printf("True! \n"); 
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
printf("False \n");
return 0;
```

Further optimization:-

```
for(i=0; i<4 ; i++){
    if ((i > b) || ((b % i) != 0))
        continue; 
    k = b/i;
    for (j=i; j<4; j++) {
        if(listA[j] == k)
        {
            printf("True! \n"); 
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to write two nested loops.

You could write a separate function.

I suppose that the original array (list) is not necessary ordered.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_multiplied( const int a[], size_t n, int value )
{
    int result = 0;

    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; !result && i < n - 1; i++ )
        {
            for ( size_t j = i + 1; !result && j < n; j++ )
            {
                result = a[i] * a[j] == value;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 2, 4 , 8 , 10 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    int value = 32;

    printf( "%s\n", is_multiplied( a, N, value ) ? "true" : "false" );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your code doesn't even compile. Id imagine you didn't put a lot of time into this.

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int b;
    int listA[4] = {2, 4 , 8 , 10};
    bool verified = false;
    printf("Enter your Extra number value \n");
    scanf("%d" ,&b);
    for(i=0; i<4 ; i++ )
    {
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++ )
        {
            if(j==i)
            {
                break;
            }
            if(listA[i] * listA[j] == b)
            {
                printf("True! \n");
                verified = true;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                //printf("False \n");
            }
        }
    }
    if(!verified)
    {
        printf("False \n");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks ! i just have two questions about ur code , one is why u added a new bool value ? cant u just return true or false without a new Boolean ? and second , is this code " if ( j==i) " means that we cant take the same number in the given list ? last question why we used the second for loop inside the first loop and not outside ? im even new to this nested for loops , thanks !